# How do we bind values to <ion-select>

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have bind the values through formController but it does not bind the correctly,
this is how i bind the values on .ts file

```
this.rental.setValue(scheme, { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
```

this is the relevant HTML

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating"> SCHEME</ion-label>
    <ion-select placeholder="Select" formControlName="rental" interface="popover">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let scheme of product" [value]="scheme">
            <p class="color-gray font-12 text-align-right bold">
                {{scheme.description}}
            </p>
        </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

product is an object array

Answer (score 0):

Also use value tag in ion-select

```html
<ion-select placeholder="Select" [value]="myVar" formControlName="rental" interface="popover">
```

Ref : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use ngModel tag in ion-select, Like

```
<ion-select placeholder="Select" [(ngModel)]="rental" interface="popover">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let scheme of product" value="scheme">
        <p class="color-gray font-12 text-align-right bold">
            {{scheme.description}}
        </p>
    </ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```